# How to manage two app using api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on rails application where we have two applications.
one is main application and second is public application. when user create/update his profile on main app then this profile should also be create/update on public app.

I am not sure what's the best way to perform to do it.

Comment: Rails engine concept 
 http://tech.taskrabbit.com/blog/2014/02/11/rails-4-engines/

Answer (score 0):

maybe those apps should share one DB or both have access to user_profiles table

Answer (score 0):

You can use Activerecord callback function in rails models like `[after_create][1]` or `[after_update][2]`. You can access the created/updated records using

```
self
```

in your callback method or you can save that in a variable like

```
object = self
```

and do whatever operation you want using that variable

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very clear what are you trying to do, but it looks like you want an admin panel separated from the public area.

If I'm right you should opt for creating a rails application with two different [Engines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html), otherwise you could use a gem like [admin_panel](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin)

Comment: I want two app first is setting application and second is public application.